# midnight hour in timevalue in access

Tags: datetime, ms-access, if-statement

I need to do some comparisons in Access 2010. I have a column where I store time(15:00; 14:45 ....)

I need to put some IF statement in an Expression Builder (I use Expression Builder coz it is easy for me)

example that works:

`=IIf([time_from]>=TimeValue("08:00"));"true result";"not true")`

I also need to put another IF:

```
=IIf([time_from]0<=TimeValue("00:00"));"true result";"not true")
```

I need to compare this time with 00:00, with midnight... but it gives me error when I enter 00:00
if I enter 23:59, than it is ok... kind of.... but it looks funny that I have to type 23:59...

is there a way around?

thanks

Comment: *"it gives me error when I enter 00:00"* - What error does it give? `TimeValue("00:00")` works fine for me (returning `00:00:00`).

Comment: to check if 15:00 is between 08:00 and 00:00 returns false.... it should say true... only if I put between 08:00 and 23:59 it works... but 00:00... probably thinks it is another day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access/VBA, `TimeValue()` values can range from `00:00:00` (midnight of a given day) to `23:59:59` (the last second of *that same day*) inclusive. If you want to test that `15:00` is between `08:00` and midnight **of the following day** you only need to test if `15:00` is `>= TimeValue("08:00")`. If you are working with one-minute resolution and want to use an ending comparison in all cases then you will in fact have to use `<= TimeValue("23:59")`.

Comment: I wanted to but I didnt have enough credits to thumbs up... now I got 10... so I can. My apologies